# jekyll syntax highlighter not working

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages, syntaxhighlighter

I'm using jekyll and Github Pages to build my website. And I followed all the instructions on http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code-snippet-highlighting, however, the syntax highlighter within my post won't render.
Below is the code:

```
{% highlight ruby %}
def print_hi(name)
  puts "Hi, #{name}"
end
print_hi('Tom')
#=> prints 'Hi, Tom' to STDOUT.
{% endhighlight %}
```

And I think the markdown file doesn't render properly, either. Can anyone tell me where I did wrong? You can check the post here: https://amir0320.github.io/blog/welcome-to-jekyll/

Comment: did you try with `\`\`\`ruby <code here> \`\`\``

Comment: @njzk2 yes, I tried it and it didn't work. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have a stale file called `main.css` inside the `css` folder of your Jekyll project, which is replacing the file generated by Jekyll from the SASS file.

i.e. Jekyll builds the `css\main.scss` and creates a file `_site\css\main.css`, but then it sees the file `css\main.css` and copies it to `_site\css\main.css`, replacing the initial file that was generated via SASS.

**Solution**: Delete this file `css\main.css`.

Comment: But if I delete the css/main.css file, where should I put my custom css file? Or the only option is to use the jekyll generated scss file?

Comment: Jekyll, by default, expects you to customize the the SASS file (main.scss), which then will generate the main.css in the end.

Comment: If you don't want to use SASS, and want to use pure CSS, then copy the generated file to the css folder, add your customizations, and delete the .scss file...

Comment: What if I've already deleted the css/main.scss file generated by jekyll? Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: `jekyll new temporary-site` - will create a temporary site with the default template... Then you can copy anything you want to your main site, and then delete the `temporary-site` folder

Comment: Caio, thank you so much! I put back the main.scss file into the css folder and the markdown works now. And then I copied my custom css styles into the css/main.scss file, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

try this in markdown file.

````
```ruby
YOUR CODE
```
````

if you can see `<code>` in output html source, but still highlight not working, that is css problem.