# noob struggle with jekyll syntax highlighting: HTML is rendered but the stylesheet seems to be missing

Tags: jekyll

I'm getting started with Jekyll. I carefully followed the step-by-step tutorial https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/01-setup/ like a good person, and everything is brilliant except that syntax highlighting is not working out of the box like the [advertisement seems to imply](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/). I've read [jekyll syntax highlighter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233170/jekyll-syntax-highlighter-not-working) but the answer didn't do it for me.

Where my markdown says, e.g.,

````
```php

namespace Foo;
use My\Thing;

$thing = new Thing();

```
````

the output is

```html
        <div class="language-php highlighter-rouge"><div class="highlight">
            <pre class="highlight"><code><span class="kn">namespace</span> <span class="nn">Foo</span><span class="p">;</span>
            <span class="kn">use</span> <span class="nn">My\Thing</span><span class="p">;</span>        
            <span class="nv">$thing</span> <span class="o">=</span> <span class="k">new</span> <span class="nx">Thing</span><span class="p">();</span>        
            </code></pre></div>
        </div>
```

but I'm not seeing any pretty colors. Obviously I am missing the CSS resource that defines `highlighter-rouge` and all that good stuff, but for all my searching I haven't been able to figure out where to get it or what I might be doing wrong.

I have tried multiple permutations of `_config.yml` with no luck, but I shouldn't need any special settings there because [the default](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/default/) is what I want.

Suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find custom syntax highlighting libraries on GitHub and elsewhere, but you may want to start with https://prismjs.com/